# Printing and using arraylists in main and other methods in Java

Tags: java, indexing, arraylist

so my main concern is how can i easily find certain values in an arraylist, for example if i have an arraylist full of names how can i easily remove it? Printing out and comparing the arraylist "studeranden" doesn't give the true value it contains, instead (i think) the position of where the value was taken, for example "[Mom1$studs@bebdb06]". How can i bypass this?

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x + " togs bort från listan");
}
//else JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, x + " hittades inte i listan");




public static class studs {
    String name;
    String matrik;
    String data;
    String x;
    studs (String namn) {
        data = namn;
        String[] parts = data.split(",");
        name = parts[0];
        matrik = parts[1];
    }

    String getstud() {
        x = name + matrik;
        return x;
    }}
```

}

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare String values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
List<String> names = ...;

names.remove( "Anton" )
```

is about all you need. You can even

```
if( names.remove( "Anton" ) ){
    System.out.println( "Anton could be removed" );
} else {
    System.out.println( "Anton doesn't study here" );
}
```

If you have a list of objects, you'll have to write some code to identify the object while you iterate the list:

```
for( int i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i ){
    Student s = students.get( i );
    if( "Anton".equals( s.getName() ) ){
        students.delete( i );
        break;
    }
}
```

To print all students, use a similar loop or:

```
for( Student s: students ){
    System.out.println( s );
}
```

But make sure your Student class contains a method

```
public String toString(){
    return this.getName(); // append more data
}
```

If you have this method, you may even

```
System.out.println( students );
```

although the arrangement (all in one line) may not please you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int xx = n_studeranden.indexOf(x);
```

This fails because the list doesn't contains String objects but studs objects. You need to iterate over the list comparing the x string with each studs' name. You can use ListIterator to remove the found element.

```
ListIterator<studs> it = studeranden.listIterator();
boolean end = false;
while (it.hasNext() && !end) {
    if (it.next().getName().equals(x)) {
        it.remove();
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int xx = n_studeranden.indexOf(x)
```

**Problem:** n_studeranden containes objects of type studs. You are looking for the index of a String.

---

```
System.out.println(n_studeranden);
```

**Problem:** If you want to print the content of the ArrayList, iterate over it and print the individual names of each element.

---

**Possitble Solution:** Like Paco said, you could iterate over each element and check whether the name matches. However, I think it would be neater to use a different data structure here. A Map of the studs name to the studs object for example so you can easily access individual studs by their name